# Veracrypt multiboot option not available

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, veracrypt

I have two SSDs in my laptop, one for Windows and one for Linux.
Both are set up for EFI boot, where I first boot grub and then Windows or Linux.

When I not attempt to encrypt my system drive in Windows via VeraCrypt, the dualboot-install option is disabled, so it doesn't see the Linux installation.

After encryption, a new EFI-entry for Veracrypt appeared in my BIOS.

When I now load Linux and try to update-grub, it doesn't notice the new Veracrypt entry.

So the only way to select my desired system on boot right now is via BIOS, which is quite uncomfortable.

Is there a way to make grub notice the Veracrypt bootloader, so I can select my boot system in grub again?

Answer (score -1):

So to complete this you will need to have gparted installed on your system and I used grub-customizer which makes playing with grub settings very simple.

1. Once you have both installed open gparted first.
2. Select the disk where your Windows/VeraCrypt is installed.
3. Right-Click on the EFI system partition and select "Information"
4. Once here you need to take note of your UUID which should look like 4563-25E2 or something like it
5. Now open Grub-Customizer and click the plus icon to add a new entry
6. Name your entry whatever you like.  Mine is VeraCrypt Windows 10
7. For Type select Other
8. Finally either copy and paste or enter the following information into the Boot Sequence box.

   ```
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod fat
   set root='hd0.gpt2'
   if[x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  4563-25E2 (Your UUID)
   else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 4563-25E2 (Your UUID)
   fi
   chainloader /EFI/VeraCrypt/DcsBoot.efi
   ```

Again all of this will assume that your Windows disk is your first disk or hd0.  If it is something else then you will need to change the above code to reflect that ie. hd1.  If you need help with any of this information then you can always select your Windows Boot Manager entry in the Grub list (if you have one) and just copy and paste the bootloader code into the window changing that very last bit:

```
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

With

```
chainloader /EFI/VeraCrypt/DcsBoot.efi
```